# DSolve Second order ODE's

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a way to use DSolve or some other mathematica function to show the first integration before getting to the final output. For example;

```
DSolve[f''[x] == 0, f[x],x]
```

Has an output of `f[x]-> C[1] + x C[2]`

But what if I want to get the first order as well f'[x], mathematica skips past this and shows the final answer. Is there anyway to get both f'[x] and f[x]

Comment: What would you want Mathematica to show for a different equation, like `f''[x] == - f[x]`?  If all you're interested in is the final value of `f'[x]`, then @ChipHurst's answer is what you need.  But if you want a "intermediate step" that would be part of a solution, that's going to be a lot harder;  there are many different techniques used to solve ODEs by hand, and not all of them even yield a value for `f'[x]` as an intermediate step.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert and Wolfram|Alpha can show the steps to solving an ODE.

Comment: I would be interested in f'[x] for problems where I have certain boundary conditions. for example f'[0] = 0 and f'[t1]=f[t2].  I would need f'[x] to find out what the constant C[1} equals at f'[x].

Comment: In case you're not aware, Mathematica can handle boundary conditions.  For example, your problem with the given boundary conditions would be solved by the command `DSolve[{f''[x] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f'[t1] == f[t2]}, f[x], x]`.  (The only answer is `f[x] -> 0` in that particular case, but a more general value for `f'[0]` gives more interesting results.)

Answer (score 3):

You can find `f'[x]` after the fact:

```
{f'[x], f[x]} /. DSolve[f''[x] == 0, f, x]
```

> ```
> {{C[2], C[1] + x C[2]}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Chip is the simplest, but just to show different approach

```
DSolve[{f''[x] == 0, f'[x] == g[x]}, {f[x], g[x]}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]